# systemd-update-utmp.service fails to load on boot up

Tags: filesystems, boot, services

`systemd-update-utmp.service` fails to load on boot up. It says it's because there's no space on the disk.

Here's the error message:

```
root@arm-64:/home/user# systemctl status systemd-update-utmp.service 
● systemd-update-utmp.service - Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-update-utmp.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-02-24 15:29:33 CET; 12min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-update-utmp.service(8)
             man:utmp(5)
    Process: 703 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-update-utmp reboot (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 703 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 24ms
 
Feb 24 15:29:33 arm-64 systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
Feb 24 15:29:33 arm-64 systemd-update-utmp[703]: Failed to write utmp record: No space left on device
Feb 24 15:29:33 arm-64 systemd[1]: systemd-update-utmp.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 24 15:29:33 arm-64 systemd[1]: systemd-update-utmp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 24 15:29:33 arm-64 systemd[1]: Failed to start Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
```

I saw [this guide](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-linux-no-space-left-on-device-error/), I checked disk space, but nothing seems wrong here. I thought it could be an issue with inodes, but according to some of you, this is not the issue. (I'm a beginner so before that I had no idea what "inodes" was...)

As requested by Giacomo Catenazzi, here's the output of `mount`:

```
root@arm-64:/home/user# mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=332724k,nr_inodes=83181,mode=755,inode64)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=94072k,mode=755,inode64)
/dev/mmcblk0p2 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro,commit=600)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k,inode64)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,inode64)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/mmcblk0p2 on /var/log.hdd type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro,commit=600)
/dev/zram0 on /var/log type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=94068k,nr_inodes=23517,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

How can I "add more space" or reconfigure whatever to fix the error ?

Comment: `/boot` will be `vfat`, which means it has no inodes at all. It's a red herring.

Comment: @Bib ok so this is not the cause of the issue ?

Comment: could you add the output of `mount`? Note: I do not think the problem is in /boot: utmp should not be written there.

Comment: Correct, utmp use files `/var/log/wtmp` & `/var/run/utmp` or `/run/utmp`, so look there and see what is strange.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi no problem, but I'll do it tomorrow

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi done